# Probability of winning mega million?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Initially I thought it would be

$\left(\frac{1}{70}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)$

to get the probability of choosing the right number out of 70 exactly 5 times and then the 6th number out of 25.

Then I saw that it was actually

${70\choose{5}}*25$

What exactly is the difference and why is the first one not correct?

Comment: $70\times 70\times 70\times 70\times 70\times 25$ is the number of sequences where order matters where you have $70$ options for the first, $70$ for the second, etc... on up to the fifth having $70$ options and $25$ options for the sixth noting again that repetition is allowed and order matters.  On the other hand $\binom{70}{5}\times 25$ counts the number of ways of choosing five numbers from $70$ followed by one number from $25$ where order does *not* matter and repetition is *not* allowed.

Answer (score 1):

For your attempts, you wouldn't want to repeat the same number. Once a number is chosen, you wouldn't want to choose it again. Also order shouldn't matter.

Also, for the answer that you show us, that can't be a probability, as it is the number of possibility. Just invert it to get the probability.

Comment: Okay so then my answer would be (1/70)(1/69)(1/68)(1/67)(1/66)(1/25) = 2.7541349e-11.
Inverting (70C5 * 25) gives 3.30496189e-9.
Why are these numbers different?

Comment: @PaulHolmes no.  That would be where repetition is not allowed but order *does* matter.  The order of the numbers should not matter.  Remember $70\cdot 69\cdots 66 \neq \binom{70}{5} = \frac{70\cdot 69\cdot 68\cdots 66}{5!}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah so if i invert (70*69*...*66)5! then I will get the right probability correct?
The incorrect assumption I made was that the 5 numbers could repeat and that order mattered? Since the order doesn't matter we multiply (70*69*...*66) by 5! correct?

Comment: Yes, with the possible additional tweak of 26 instead of 25 depending on which lottery you are referring to.